# Positioning Page Elements with Regard to Center

Tags: css, web, html

How should I place elements absolutely on a page, with respect to another element's place on the same page? I have centered a jpg using css, "position: center;", and now I want to make it so that the elements I place around that jpg and throughout the page, are off-center by a certain amount of pixels, with respect to that jpg.

Comment: Post some code please? Or better yet, a jsFiddle.

Comment: "position: center;" doesn't exist, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Comment: you can position an image center by using margin: 0 auto; To position things around an image, you will have to make the image position relative and position things absolute to the image. Ex http://jsfiddle.net/a4uodadp/1/

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me, all. Here's the code I've put in thus far.                                    .bg1 {
     position: center;
     top: 0px;
     z-index: 0;
    }

Comment: What I want to do now is place pictures over this background picture, but have it so that they're positioned FROM center on ANY browser window visitors may be using

Comment: Basically so that the page shows up the exact same on any computer screen size

Comment: @Zach See my answer. Do not use z-index to make a backgroundimage. Create a div and add css for that div, background-image: url('image-path');. FYI, when you position an element relative to another you start from the top left and not the center. It would be easier if you showed more code or a drawing of what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Position: center; is not valid code, use margin: 0 auto;

You have to set the background image as position: relative; and everything else absolute to that background image. See fiddle.

```
    .my-image {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 256px;
    height: 256px;
    background-image: url('http://ocmapdb.wdfiles.com/local--files/mapper:shadowsand/White%20Tiger%20Head.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
```

Here is an image position to the background image.

```
  .image-two {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 50px;
  }
```

The HTML

```
<div class="my-image">
    <img class="image-two" src="http://www.iconshock.com/img_jpg/SUPERVISTA/animals/jpg/256/tiger_icon.jpg">
</div>
```

[see example](http://jsfiddle.net/a4uodadp/2/)

Answer (score 0):

To get the position of an element and set another element to its position, use JS; something like this:

**JS**

Where in the following JS, img is the "thing" that you want to get the position from

- Use $("elem") where elem is a DOM object
- Use $(".myClass") where .myClass is the class of the object you are
  trying to access.
- Use $("#myId") where #myId is the id of the DOM object you are trying to access. Note: Id's **MUST** be unique. Your HTML is invalid if the same id appears more than once in your HTML code

If you have multiple items that you want to get the position of, you can use a loop the following way to get their positions (applies to classes or multiple DOM objects:

```
var numItems = $(".myClass").length;
for(i = 0; i < numItems; i++) {
    var myImageTop = $(".something:eq("+i+")").offset().top;
    var myImageLeft = $(".something:eq("+i+")").offset().left;
    var myImageWidth = $(".something:eq("+i+")").outerWidth();
    var myImageHeight = $(".something:eq("+i+")").outerHeight();

    //Then the elements you want to change the position of. You can access specific elements the same way we access specific elements above (using `:eq()`)
}
```

Use the following if you don't need to loop (only one element to position by)

```
var myImageTop = $("img").offset().top;
var myImageLeft = $("img").offset().left;
var myImageWidth = $("img").outerWidth();
var myImageHeight = $("img").outerHeight();

$(".something").css({
    top: myImageTop + "px",
    left: myImageLeft + "px" //, //Uncomment the comma if you uncomment one of the following lines
    //width: myImageWidth + "px" //, //Uncomment this line if you want this element to match the original image's width, uncomment the comma if you uncomment the next line
    //height: myImageHeight + "px" //Uncomment this line if you want this element to match the original image's height
});
```

If you want to place an element to the right of the image, simply add the `myImageLeft` and `myImageWidth` variables and if you want to place an element under it add the `myImageTop` and `myImageHeight` variables.

If you want to place them above, you can get the element's height and subtract it from `myImageTop`, similarly, if you want to place the image to the left, you can get the element's width and subtract it from `myImageLeft`

**Note:** The elements you want to set positions for (not the elements you are getting the position from - although they can have `position:` relative, absolute, or fixed) should have `position:fixed;`

As Guilherme mentioned, `position:center;` does not exist, so avoid using this for positioning elements. http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp shows the positioning properties. [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) is the link Guilherme provided.

If you want to centre items inside the parent, you can use `margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;` on the element (assuming the parent element has `position:relative;` or a set width). If what you are trying to centre is text, you can use `text-align:center;` so long as the DOM object (i.e. `<p></p>`, `<span></span>`, `<div></div>` [to name a few]) has a set width. When I say set width, this can be done many ways, view [this](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_width.asp) for more detail.

Comment: Wow, this is awesome, I'm completely new to StackOverflow, and these responses have been great, thanks everyone! I'll post more if I'm running into any difficulty with the info you've given me